# How to disable nativeEncodign/nativeDecoding for the whole Binder with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_record_serialization_and_deserialization) it indicates that to disable `nativeEncoding/nativeDedoding` is done at the binding level, for example:

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.nativeDecoding: false`

However, is there any way to disable native encoding/decoding globally for all producers/consumers of a `kstream` type binder?

I have tried the following combinations with no results:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.consumerProperties.useNativeDecoding=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.consumer.useNativeDecoding=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.useNativeDecoding=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.default.consumer.useNativeDecoding=false
```

spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams v3.1.5.

Comment: Isn't native encoding/decoding `false` by default?

Comment: hI @OlegZhurakousky!!! as far as I can see this line of the KStreamBoundElementFactory class is set to true by default: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/KStreamBoundElementFactory.java#L83